# How to evaluate an object property in ui-ace?

Tags: angularjs

I need to evaluate `{{ results.example }}` in a template like this one:

```
<div ng-model='example' ui-ace="aceOptions">{{ results.example }}</div>
```

But it doesn't work. It works only with a single scope variable like this `{{ example }}`.

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ktsgyLmb/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also change the ng-model

```
<div ng-model='results.example' ui-ace="aceOptions">{{ results.example }}</div>
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/9h35894w/)